# CSS Hover: Reduce image box + zoom image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

I hope someone can help me. I want to animate an image with a hover effect using Wordpress. If you move the mouse over the image, the image should enlarge, but the image box should decrease at the same time.

Here is an example of how I imagine it:

https://solene.qodeinteractive.com/ (If you scroll down to Authentic Photos)

So far I have placed the image in wordpress and inserted the following code in custom css:

```
.elementor-5528 .elementor-element.elementor-element-e19f93f .elementor-image img:hover {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   -webkit-transform: scale (1.3);
   transform: scale (1.2);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
   transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

However, the image including the image box is now enlarged. What else do I have to add so that the image box does not increase in size with the image, but rather decreases in size?
I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

Best regards,
Julia

Comment: Hello. Make a reproducible example, pls.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean? Sorry i'm new here. I have added an example as a link.

Answer (score 0):

On hover we crop the size of the parent container and at the same time we scale a child image. That's it.

Please, check this at codepen:

css

```
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform ease 0.5s;
}
div:hover {
  clip-path: inset(12px 12px 12px 12px);
}
div:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

html:

```
<div>
  <img alt="image" src="https://solene.qodeinteractive.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/h1-port-feauture-img-2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is it! Thank you very much Maxim! Can you maybe tell me how to integrate it into wordpress? I'll take the html code in the backend and where do I have to insert the css so that it connects to my picture? I only have Css available under Customizer> Custom CSS. but when i insert the css code, it applies it to everything and not just to the photo. I am still a complete beginner and have not yet fully understood how to integrate this.

Comment: It'll be extremely difficult to do something without the access to the site's source code. So all I can do is to give you a general advice: open the page where you want to apply this effect; inspect the source code and find the `img` tag; write down a distinguished class name from the img tag and a class name from its parent tag; replace a `div` tag from the example above with the parent's class name as follows: `.parentImgClass {...` then replace  a `img` tag in the example above with the image class as well. Insert the edited example into the custom css code on your site.